# Unable to deploy firebase functions using CloudBuild(Error setting up the execution environment for your function..)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

## Question

I want to deploy firebase functions using CloudBuild.

But, the following error occurs and cannot be deployed.

```
.
.
.
Step #2: [2019-11-28T05:30:33.984Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 content-type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, vary=X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding, date=Thu, 28 Nov 2019 05:30:33 GMT, server=ESF, cache-control=private, x-xss-protection=0, x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN, x-content-type-options=nosniff, accept-ranges=none, transfer-encoding=chunked
Step #2: [2019-11-28T05:30:35.986Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Step #2:
Step #2: [2019-11-28T05:30:36.433Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 content-type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, vary=X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding, date=Thu, 28 Nov 2019 05:30:36 GMT, server=ESF, cache-control=private, x-xss-protection=0, x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN, x-content-type-options=nosniff, accept-ranges=none, transfer-encoding=chunked
Step #2: [2019-11-28T05:30:38.436Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Step #2:
Step #2: ⚠ functions[func-example(asia-northeast1)]: Deployment error.
Step #2: Error setting up the execution environment for your function. Please try deploying again after a few minutes.
Step #2:
Step #2:
Step #2: Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
Step #2: func-example
Step #2:
Step #2:
Step #2: To try redeploying those functions, run:
Step #2: firebase deploy --only functions:func-example
Step #2:
Step #2:
Step #2: To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
Step #2: firebase deploy --except functions
Step #2: [2019-11-28T05:30:38.912Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 content-type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, vary=X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding, date=Thu, 28 Nov 2019 05:30:38 GMT, server=ESF, cache-control=private, x-xss-protection=0, x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN, x-content-type-options=nosniff, accept-ranges=none, transfer-encoding=chunked
Step #2:
Step #2: Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
Finished Step #2
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/project-id-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/firebase" failed: exit status 1
```

How can I resolve this error?
I tried deploying every few hours for 2 days but it didn't work.

## Situation

The situation is as follows.

### cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
  # because node10 is used
  - name: 'node:10.16.3'
    entrypoint: 'yarn'
    dir: 'functions'
    args: ['install']
  # because a grpc error occurs
  - name: 'gcr.io/${_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}/firebase'
    entrypoint: 'npm'
    dir: 'functions'
    args: ['rebuild']
  # container already created
  - name: 'gcr.io/${_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}/firebase'
    args:
      ['deploy', '--only', 'functions:trigger', '--debug', '--project', '${_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}']
    env:
      - 'FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=${_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}'
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "deploy": "firebase use xxx && firebase deploy --only functions",
    "deploy:func-example": "firebase use xxx && firebase deploy --only functions:func-example"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    .
    .
    .
  },
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

### manual deploy

Manual deployment is successful.

```
$ yarn deploy

yarn run v1.15.2
$ firebase use xxx && firebase deploy --only functions
Now using alias xxx (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)

=== Deploying to 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /var/folders/7l/wbcfr4yn5wq8zyntjxg1_hc0ygjdjv/T/yarn--1574914184465-0.44163642642000567/node but npm is using /Users/sekiguchi_t/.anyenv/envs/nodenv/versions/10.16.3/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> functions@0.0.0 build /xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> tsc

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (226.54 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 (Beta) function func-example(asia-northeast1)...
✔  scheduler: all necessary APIs are enabled
✔  functions[func-example(asia-northeast1)]: Successful update operation. 

✔  Deploy complete!
```

Comment: Hi, please [create a Cloud Functions issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491477&template=1161411) and provide your project id as well as all the necessary steps and a minimal working example in order for the engineers to thoroughly investigate and attempt to diagnose this issue. Creating the Issue Tracker entry with the given link above will create it in a private component so you can safely share all the aforementioned information, only visible to people CC'd, you and other Googlers

Answer (score 1):

There could be a couple of reasons, one of them is you need to send your `.env` file containing your service account variables along with it, Since Firebase uploads the whole functions folder during the deployment process and performs some sort of execution tests on their end.

one way of doing that is convert your `.env` file to a base64 string

`cat .env | base64`

and save it in the cloud as an environment variable eg. SERVICE_ACCOUNT.

Just before deploy command, convert base64 string back to `.env` file in the functions folder.

`echo $SERVICE_ACCOUNT | base64 -d > .env`